# How can I handle POST method using NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, axios, next.js13

so I'm trying to learn NextJs(TS), Prisma and MySQL and I'm trying to apply my knowledge in ReactJS but it seems that I'm having a bit of trouble when I'm trying to Call my `POST`.

This is my directory.
[image]

I get this error

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/addUser 404 (Not Found)

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'debug' in 'C:\Users\Student\Desktop\nextprisma\node_modules\follow-redirects'
Did you mean './debug'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, C:\Users\Student\Desktop\nextprisma).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/follow-redirects/debug.js
./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/adapters.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js
./node_modules/axios/index.js
./app/add/AddUser.tsx
```

This is my form. AddUser.tsx

```
const AddUser = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        try {
          const response = await axios.post('/api/addUser', data);
    
          if (response.status === 200) {
            const newPost = response.data;
            console.log('New post:', newPost);
          } else {
            console.error('Failed to create post');
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        }
      };

    const handleChange = (e:any) => {
        setData((prevData) => ({...prevData, [e.target.name]:e.target.value}))
    }

  return (
    <form className='flex flex-col gap-2' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className='flex gap-2'>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>

        <div className='flex gap-2'>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="name" onChange={handleChange} />
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className='border-2 bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-500/90 py-2 px-4'> Add </button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default AddUser
```

This is my app/api/addUser.ts

```
export const addUser = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
    try {
      const { name, email } = req.body;
  
      const newPost = await prisma.user.create({
        data: {
          email,
          name,
        },
      });
  
      console.log(newPost);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

With NextJS 13+, the directory structure has changed and you need to have it setup correctly to avoid 404 error for API routes.

This is how it should be

```
├── app/
│   ├── page.tsx
│   └── api /
│       ├── user/
│       │   ├── [id]/
│       │   │   └── route.ts
│       │   └── route.ts
│       ├── order/
│       │   └── route.ts
│       └── .. and so on 
├── public
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── next.config.js
└── ...and everything else at the root level
```

The `route.ts` file is a simple handler for different routes for the `/api` route. File should be:

`route.ts` file

```
import { NextResponse } from "@/node_modules/next/server";

// Handles GET request @ /api/user
export async function GET(req: Request) {
  // add route logic
  return NextResponse.json({ anyObj: {} });
}

// Same for post, patch
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  // add route logic
  return NextResponse.json({ anyObj: {} });
}
```

With those 2 things in place, you should be able to get your APIs running! Just make sure you read the documentation on [api routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) and follow it. It covers various things such as getting request body, params & more.

Good luck!